# How to delete a specific line from record in C programming (it can't proceed deletion)

Tags: c, search, replace, report

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct person{
 char stdNumb [20];
    char firstName [20],lastName [20], icPass [20], nationality [20], gender [20], dateOfBirth [20];
    char contact [20], address [30];
};

void appendData(){
  FILE *fp;
  struct person obj;
  fp=fopen("D:\\data.txt","a");
  printf("\n============================");
  printf("\n            ADD");
  printf("\n============================\n\n");

  printf("Student Number: ");
  scanf("%s",&obj.stdNumb);

  printf("First Name: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s",obj.firstName);

  printf("Last Name: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s",&obj.lastName);

  printf("IC/ Passport: ");
  scanf("%s",&obj.icPass);

  printf("Nationality: ");
  scanf("%s",obj.nationality);

  printf("Gender: ");
  scanf("%s",&obj.gender);

  printf("Date of Birth: ");
  scanf("%s",obj.dateOfBirth);

  printf("Contact: ");
  scanf("%s", &obj.contact);

  printf("Address: ");
  scanf(" %[^\n]s", &obj.address);

  fprintf(fp,"\n%s\n%s %s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", obj.stdNumb, obj.firstName, obj.lastName, obj.icPass, obj.nationality, obj.gender, obj.dateOfBirth, obj.contact, obj.address);
  fclose(fp);
}

void editRecord()
{
  FILE *fp;
  struct person obj;

  fp=fopen("D:\\data.txt","r");
  printf("\n============================");
  printf("\n            EDIT");
  printf("\n============================\n\n");
  while(!feof(fp))
  {
  fscanf(fp,"%s\n%s\n",obj.firstName,&obj.stdNumb);
  printf("%s\n%s\n",obj.firstName,obj.stdNumb);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  getch();
}

void searchRecord()
{
  FILE *fp;
  struct person obj;
  char number[20];
  int totrec=0;
  fp=fopen("D:\\data.txt","r");
  printf("\n\n============================");
  printf("\n           SEARCH");
  printf("\n============================");
  printf("\nEnter student number to search  : ");
  scanf("%s",&number);
  while(!feof(fp))
  {
      fscanf(fp,"\n%s\n%s %s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", obj.stdNumb, obj.firstName, obj.lastName, obj.icPass, obj.nationality, obj.gender, obj.dateOfBirth, obj.contact, obj.address);
  if(strcmpi(obj.stdNumb,number)==0){
    printf("\nStudent Number : %s",obj.stdNumb);
    printf("\n\nName   :  %s",obj.firstName);
    totrec++;
     }
  }
  if(totrec==0)
     printf("\n\n\nNo Data Found");
  else
     printf("\n\n===Total %d Record found===",totrec);
  fclose(fp);
  getch();
}

void deleteRecord()
{
FILE *fp, *fdel;
struct person obj;
char number[20];
fflush(stdin);
printf("\n============================");
printf("\n            DELETE");
printf("\n============================\n\n");
printf("Enter student number to delete  :");
scanf("%s", number);
fp=fopen("D:\\student.txt","r");
fdel=fopen("D:\\del.txt","w");
while(fscanf(fp,"\n%s\n%s %s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", obj.stdNumb, obj.firstName, obj.lastName, obj.icPass, obj.nationality, obj.gender, obj.dateOfBirth, obj.contact, obj.address)!=0);
{
    if(stricmp(number, obj.stdNumb)!=0)
        fprintf(fdel,"\n%s\n%s %s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", obj.stdNumb, obj.firstName, obj.lastName, obj.icPass, obj.nationality, obj.gender, obj.dateOfBirth, obj.contact, obj.address);
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fdel);
remove("D:\\data.txt");
rename("D:\\del.txt","D:\\data.txt"); 

printf("Successully Deleted.");
getch();
}

void main()
{
char choice;
while(1)
{
    printf("\n============================");
    printf("\n            MENU");
    printf("\n============================");
    printf("\n1. ADD");
    printf("\n2. SEARCH");
    printf("\n3. EDIT");
    printf("\n4. DELETE");
    printf("\n5. EXIT");
    printf("\n============================");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Enter your choice : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    choice = getche();
    switch(choice)
    {
    case'1' : //call append record
        appendData();
        break;
    case'2' : //call search record
        searchRecord();
        break;
    case'3' : //edit record
        editRecord();
        break;
    case'4' : //Read all record
        deleteRecord();
        break;
    case'5':
         exit(0);
defaut:
        printf("ss");
    }
}
```

}

Here is my full code. I'm done with append and search. The problem is, when I try to run, and delete a record, it doesn't work after I input the student number. How to fix this?

Comment: You might need to give us a bit more information. Why 'can't it proceed?'

Comment: if i have entered the student number as input, it doesn't delete the record..

Answer (score 1):

You try to read in a string with `scanf("%s", &number);` but `number` is already a pointer so you need to write `scanf("%s", number);`.

When you normally try to read in something with `scanf` you need to give it an address which points to the place where the value shall be stored.

So when i have something like

```
int a;
scanf("%d", &a);
```

you give scanf the address of `a`.

```
char str[100];
scanf("%s", str);
```

Here str is already a pointer to a char array.
That is why we don't need to add the address operator `&`.

But when you add the address operator you give `scanf` the address were the pointer value is stored.

**EDIT:**
I compiled your code with clang on my machine and it warns me about 7 `scanf` statements:

```
a.c:20:11: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
  scanf("%s",&obj.stdNumb);
         ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:26:12: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
  scanf(" %[^\n]s",&obj.lastName);
          ~^~~     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:29:11: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
  scanf("%s",&obj.icPass);
         ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:35:11: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
  scanf("%s",&obj.gender);
         ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:41:11: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
  scanf("%s", &obj.contact);
         ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:44:12: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[30]' [-Wformat]
  scanf(" %[^\n]s", &obj.address);
          ~^~~      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.c:61:19: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
  fscanf(fp,"%s\n%s\n",obj.firstName,&obj.stdNumb);
```

and three typos

```
a.c:83:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strcmpi' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if(strcmpi(obj.stdNumb,number)==0){
     ^
a.c:112:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'stricmp' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if(stricmp(number, obj.stdNumb)!=0)
       ^
a.c:141:14: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getche' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    choice = getche();
             ^
```

Comment: I've changed it, but it still doesnt work.. maybe it's not the problem..

Comment: `scanf("%s",&obj.stdNumb);`
and 
`scanf(" %[^\n]s",&obj.lastName);`
there you do it again

Comment: but, here i can run my program.. the problem is only at delete menu..

Comment: @Monica Panjaitan A compiler warning means that there could be something wrong, but the compiler can't see if it is ok or not. So it will compile the code, because the compiler says the user knows what he is doing.

Comment: now, i can delete the record, but it stiil has problem in specifying the line.. if i 5 students in file, and i wanna delete student 2, it will delete all record except student 1, but if i wanna delete student 1, it will delete all records.. how to fix it? thanks :)